Angelology - Angels vs. Seraphim/Cherubim/Ophanim
My question is forthcoming at the end of my paragraph:
Every time in Scripture a cherub or seraph is mentioned, not once have I ever seen an explicit connection to angels. Not once have I ever seen the Bible explicitly call cherubim or seraphim a "class of angels." Not even an implication, other than them both serving God as spiritual beings. YET, it is so popular in the church today to speak of them as if they are a type of angel. Where in Biblical data does this come from, if anywhere? If this is a misconception, when in church history did it begin? Does it not more so seem from the Biblical data that cherubim / seraphim are not a class of angel, but different spiritual beings that serve God, different entirely?
In the Bible, cherubim / seraphim always (1) have wings (2) have an animal-like appearance (bear, eagle, etc.) (3) sometimes have eyes all around (4) seem to usually protect God's throne / presence
In the Bible angels (1) not once are ever described with wings. You won't find a verse saying "wings" with "angel(s)" anywhere in Scripture. Perhaps flying somewhere, but no wings mentioned (2) when they take human form, they can be confused as humans, looking just like them (3) are God's messengers often leaving God's throneroom to deliver messages, serve Christians etc.
Am I the only one confused why so many Christians today assume cherubim as a "type" or "class" of angel as if it were a fact, while the Bible seems to consistently describe angels as a different being entirely? Am I missing something?

I agree with you. 'Cherubim' is a concept ; they are not individuals/beings. 'Seraphim' also. I agree also, that 'angels' are never described as having wings, but an angel 'flies in the midst of heaven', it is true. I have written a book called 'The Cherubim of Glory' which is freely available on my website (see my profile). Good question. Up-voted +1.

True - most of this is Christiam and Jewish myth that is not in the Bible.

also...  the word translated as "angel" is often "ben-elohim" - literally one of the sons of God or "the gods." Other times it is "malak": a messenger.

@DanFefferman, I was well aware that angels are often referred to as "Sons of God" in Scripture. What I was not aware of was that English translations sometimes translate "ben-elohim" as "angels" in their translation - that's new to me! Could you please provide an example or two? Does the ESV (my translation of choice) ever do this?

It is true that much pious myth has grown up around the idea of divine angels.  Here are the Biblical facts:
Seraphim
Seraphim are fiery serpents in Num 21:6, 8, Deut 8:15, Isa 14:29, 30:6 - in these last two cases, they also fly.
However, in Isa 6:2, 6, these seraphim fly and attend the throne of God and have six wings.  Whether they are angels or not is unstated.
Cherubim
Cherubim are heavenly beings who:

are closely connected with the throne of God as per Ps 18:10, 2 Sam 22:11, and these cherubim can fly.  See also 1 Sam 4:4, 2 Sam 6:2, 2 Kings 19:15, Isa 37:16, Ps 80:2, 99:1.  To represent such beings, two cherubim were mounted on the mercy seat of the ark of the covenant with wings as per Ex 25:18-22, 37:7-9, Num 7:89.  Further the description of the four living creatures surrounding the throne of God in Eze 1, with wings, are also described as Cherubim in Eze 9:, 10:1, 11:22
Two Cherubim we used to guard the entrance to the garden of Eden, Gen 3:24.
Cherubim were also embroidered into the hangings in the sanctuary complete with wings, Ex 26:1, 31, 36:8, 35, etc.

Again, whether cherubim are a classification of heavenly angels is unstated.
It is Jewish and Christian tradition (really pious myth) that classifies both Cherubim and seraphim as classes of heavenly angels.
Ophanim
Ophanim is the ordinary Hebrew word for "wheels", eg, chariot wheels, Ex 14:25, etc.  See also 1 Kings 7:30, 32, 33, Prov 20:36, etc.
It is only in Eze 1, and Eze 3:13, and Eze 10 that very mystical, specialized wheels are associated with the throne of God.

"these seraphim" is a confusing term. The seraphim that bit people in Numbers are almost different from the seraphim that attend the throne of God, just as the serpent of Genesis is not the same species as the normal serpents referred to elsewhere.

@DanFefferman - agreed - but the word is the same - it is clearly used in different ways.
